# call more than one function on button click in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

How can I call more than one function on my confirm delete button?

Here are the functions I need to call:

```
    function ifnull() {
                if (selected_devices_area = "") {
                    window.alert("Please select devices!");
                }
            }

    function submitForm() {

                if (confirm("Do you really want to delete these devices?")) {
                    //document.location.href = '/site/service/device/DeleteMultipleDevices.asp?siteId=<%=iSiteId%>&serviceId=<%=iServiceId%>';

                    document.device.submit();
                    window.alert('Devices successfully deleted.');

                }
```

The HTML for the button:

```
        <tr>    
            <td><a href="/site/service/serviceinfo_main.asp?siteId=<%=iSiteId%> &crType=Delete Multiple Devices&addCr=yes&crId=<%=iCrId %>"class="btnLink">&laquo; Back</a></td>
            <td class="tdRight"><a href="javascript:ifnull();javascript:submitForm();" class="btnLink">Confirm Deletion &raquo;</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I am calling the functions like this but it's not working.

Comment: Looks like you're mixing client side and server side coding. You can't do that. Better use AJAX instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prefix with "javascript:" twice. Instead of

```
<a href="javascript:ifnull();javascript:submitForm();" class="btnLink">
```

Do

```
<a href="javascript:ifnull();submitForm();" class="btnLink">
```

But more to the point, if I understood correctly if `ifnull()` is not passed - you don't want to submit the form. If so, change your `ifnull()` function to:

```
function ifnull() {
   if (selected_devices_area = "") {
       window.alert("Please select devices!");
       return true
   } else {
       return false
   }
}
```

then you can change your `submitForm()` function to

```
function submitForm() {
   if (!ifnull() && confirm("Do you really want to delete these devices?")) {
        document.device.submit();
        // You should generate "alert('Devices successfully deleted.');" from server side
        // since as of now you don't know that is really happend
}
```

and change your call to

```
<a href="submitForm();" class="btnLink">
```

This way it more logicaly concise.

Comment: //I tried to get the value of vbscript variable value like thisvar check_null = '<%= selected_devices_area %>';
        function ifnull()
         {
            if (check_null = "")
             {
                window.alert("Please select devices!");
                return true
            } 
            else {
                return false
            }
        }

Comment: What's selected_devices_area where and how it's declared?